# Add a summary row with totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, rollup

I know this sounds crazy and probably should not be done this way but I need something like this - I have a records from `SELECT [Type], [Total Sales] From Before`

I want to add an extra row at the end to show the SUM at the end of the table (After). Could this be done?

[image]

Comment: Sql Server has support for subtotals: [see with rollup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2008 or later version, you can use the [`ROLLUP()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495.aspx) GROUP BY function:

```
SELECT
  Type = ISNULL(Type, 'Total'),
  TotalSales = SUM(TotalSales)
FROM atable
GROUP BY ROLLUP(Type)
;
```

This assumes that the `Type` column cannot have NULLs and so the NULL in this query would indicate the rollup row, the one with the grand total. However, if the `Type` column can have NULLs of its own, the more proper type of accounting for the total row would be like in @Declan_K's answer, i.e. using the [`GROUPING()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544.aspx) function:

```
SELECT
  Type = CASE GROUPING(Type) WHEN 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE Type END,
  TotalSales = SUM(TotalSales)
FROM atable
GROUP BY ROLLUP(Type)
;
```

Answer (score 31):

This is the more powerful grouping / rollup syntax you'll want to use in SQL Server 2008+. Always useful to specify the version you're using so we don't have to guess.

```
SELECT 
  [Type] = COALESCE([Type], 'Total'), 
  [Total Sales] = SUM([Total Sales])
FROM dbo.Before
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(([Type]),());
```

Craig Freedman wrote [a great blog post introducing `GROUPING SETS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/craigfr/grouping-sets-in-sql-server-2008).

Answer (score 21):

Try to use `union all` as below

```
SELECT [Type], [Total Sales] From Before
union all
SELECT 'Total', Sum([Total Sales]) From Before
```

if you have problem with ordering, as **i-one** suggested try this:

```
select [Type], [Total Sales] 
from (SELECT [Type], [Total Sales], 0 [Key] 
      From Before 
      union all 
      SELECT 'Total', Sum([Total Sales]), 1 From Before) sq 
order by [Key], Type
```

Comment: Minor note here, if values of Type are alphabetical after the word (U,V,W,etc. ) Total,    then Total line might not appear on the bottom row...

Comment: I agree with @Sparky, this way it should be e.g. `select [Type], [Total Sales] from (SELECT [Type], [Total Sales], 0 [Key] From Before union all SELECT 'Total', Sum([Total Sales]), 1 From Before) sq order by [Key], Type`

Comment: Without knowing the possible values of [Type], Cast() to VarChar(5) won't really address it. i-one shows the right solution, added a numeric counter to force the sort order...

Comment: Another note: the UNION ALL variants of this will require two scans instead of one.

Answer (score 16):

You could use the [ROLLUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) operator

```
SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN (GROUPING([Type]) = 1) THEN 'Total'
            ELSE [Type] END AS [TYPE]
        ,SUM([Total Sales]) as Total_Sales
From    Before
GROUP BY
        [Type] WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display more column values without an aggregation function use `GROUPING SETS` instead of `ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT
  Type = ISNULL(Type, 'Total'),
  SomeIntColumn = ISNULL(SomeIntColumn, 0),
  TotalSales = SUM(TotalSales)
FROM atable
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((Type, SomeIntColumn ), ())
ORDER BY SomeIntColumn --Displays summary row as the first row in query result
```

Comment: I liked this solution. If you want to query and retrieve results from more than two columns then this is the good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Need more specifics with your question but say "type" is from table called letters and "sales" is from a table called transactions. You can use UNION ALL.

```
SELECT type, COUNT(sales) "total sales"
FROM letters
GROUP BY type
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', COUNT(sales) "total sales"
FROM transactions
```