# Overall summary with multiple GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, rollup, grouping-sets

Lets say I have a table called `census` with the following information:

```
COUNTRY     PROVINCE    CITY        POPULATION
==============================================
USA         California  Sacramento  1234
USA         California  SanFran     4321
USA         Texas       Houston     1111
USA         Texas       Dallas      2222
Canada      Ontario     Ottawa      3333
Canada      Manitoba    Winnipeg    4444
```

I'm building a report at the country/province level, which gives me the following:

```
SELECT country, province, SUM(population)
FROM census
GROUP BY country, province;

COUNTRY     PROVINCE    SUM(POPULATION)
=======================================
USA         California  5555
USA         Texas       3333
Canada      Ontario     3333
Canada      Manitoba    4444
```

I'm looking to have an "overall summary" row included on the report, so that the final result looks like:

```
COUNTRY     PROVINCE    SUM(POPULATION)
=======================================
USA         California   5555
USA         Texas        3333
Canada      Ontario      3333
Canada      Manitoba     4444
TOTAL                   16665
```

I'm acquainted with `ROLLUP`s, but I can't seem to find a combination that gets me what I'm looking for.   Using `GROUP BY ROLLUP(country, province)` includes the total value I want, but it also includes a large number of extra values which I don't care about.  This is also true with `GROUP BY ROLLUP(country), province`

How can I go about making the "total" record?
I'm currently calculating it with a `UNION ALL` and repeating 90% of the first query with a different `GROUP BY`, but because the first query is non-trivial, the result is slow and ugly code.

Here's a SQL Fiddle for those who want to play with this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12ad9/5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a summary row with totals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934318/add-a-summary-row-with-totals)

Comment: @Bulat - That's for a single column in a `GROUP BY` and uses SQL Server specific syntax.

Comment: Well, you can find the same answer there and give it a vote. If only the number of columns and their names were important... And still it is a +1 for the well presented question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I finally came up two approaches that are flexible and don't make me feel like a terrible programmer.

---

The first solution involves [`GROUPING SETS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/aggreg.htm#DWHSG8631).
What I'm essentially trying to do is group the expression at two different levels: one at the overall level, and one at the `(country, province)` level.

If I were to split the query into two parts and use a `UNION ALL`, one half would have a `GROUP BY country, province` and the other would lack a grouping clause.  The un-grouped section can also be represented as `GROUP BY ()` if we feel like it.  This will come in handy in a moment.

That gives us something like:

```
SELECT country, province, SUM(population)
FROM census
GROUP BY country, province
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS country, NULL AS province, SUM(population)
FROM census
GROUP BY ();
```

The query works, but it doesn't scale well.  The more calculations you need to make, the more time you spend repeating yourself.

By using a `GROUPING SETS`, I can specify that I want the data grouped in two different ways:

```
SELECT country, province, SUM(population)
FROM census
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS( (country, province), () );
```

Now we're getting somewhere!  But what about our result row?  How can we detect it and label it accordingly?  That's where the [`GROUPING`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/aggreg.htm#DWHSG8622) function comes in.  It returns a 1 if the column is NULL because of a GROUP BY statement.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN GROUPING(country) = 1 THEN 'TOTAL'
        ELSE country
    END AS country,
    province,
    SUM(population),
    GROUPING(country) AS grouping_flg
FROM census
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (country, province), () );
```

---

If we don't like the `GROUPING SETS` approach, we can still use a traditional [`ROLLUP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/aggreg.htm#i1007413) but with a minor change.

Instead of passing each column to the `ROLLUP` individually, we pass the collection of columns as a set by encasing them in parentheses.  This makes it so the set of columns is treated as a *single* group instead of *multiple* groups.  The following query will give you the same results as the previous:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN GROUPING(country) = 1 THEN 'TOTAL'
        ELSE country
    END AS country,
    province,
    SUM(population),
    GROUPING(country) AS grouping_flg
FROM census
GROUP BY ROLLUP( (country, province) );
```

---

Feel free to try both approaches for yourself!
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12ad9/102

Answer (score 13):

This is exactly what **[`GROUPING SETS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/aggreg.htm#i1006842)** expressions was designed to do:

```
SELECT country, province, SUM(population)
FROM census
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
   ( (country, province),        -- first group by country and province
     ()                          -- then by (nothing), i.e. a total grouping
   );
```

See the [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12ad9/56)

Comment: Cool!  Now how do I detect the summary row with the `GROUPING` function?  I can't seem to pass it anything without it throwing an error.  I also found out that `ROLLUP( (country, province) )` works too but you beat me to the answer. :D

Comment: Disregard my previous comment.  `GROUPING` returns 1 when the column is null because of a ROLLUP, so `GROUPING(country)` and `GROUPING(province)` both work.

Comment: By the way (regarding your deleted answer), `GROUP BY 1` means something else usually. `GROUP BY ()` is actually valid SQL for an overall group by, equivalent to not having a group by clause..

Comment: @Mr.Llama: Please consider posting your `ROLLUP( (country, province) )` solution as an answer. It makes perfect sense in your scenario and I personally find it clearer than this answer, however much I may like upvoting ypercube's posts.

Comment: @Mr.Llama, AndriyM is right, the `GROUP BY ROLLUP( (country, province) )` should be an answer - and certainly not in the question. Please add it in your answer (and undelete.)

Comment: @ypercube - Undeleted my answer and added an explanation for both the `GROUP BY` and `ROLLUP` approaches.

Comment: Hello sir, is it possible to get summary w.r.t each group i.e group summary?

Comment: @SagarChaudhary yes, just add another grouping set. E.g.: `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (country, province), (country), () );` to add summaries per country as well.

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle you can do this with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT coalesce(c.country, 'Total') as province, c.country, SUM(c.population)
FROM census c
GROUP BY ROLLUP(c.country, c.province)
HAVING c.province is not null or
       c.province is null and c.country is null;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12ad9/50) is the SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind is filter out the sub-totals after the `rollup` is applied:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT   country, province, SUM (population)
        FROM     census
        GROUP BY ROLLUP (country, province))
WHERE  province IS NOT NULL OR country IS NULL;
```

---

You can accomplish the same thing a little more compactly by using `GROUPING_ID` in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT   country,
         province,
         SUM (population)
FROM     census
GROUP BY ROLLUP (country, province)
HAVING   GROUPING_ID (country, province) <> 1
```

---

And, as @Anssssss pointed out, you can also use the criteria from the `WHERE` clause in the first answer in a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT   country, province, SUM (population)
FROM     census
GROUP BY ROLLUP (country, province)
HAVING   province IS NOT NULL OR country IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do use a Union:

```
SELECT country, province, SUM(population)
FROM census
GROUP BY country, province
UNION
SELECT
   'Total', '', SUM(population)
FROM census
```

Comment: The original poster said they were already doing a UNION and it was inefficient and "ugly". The SQL fiddle showed this in detail. They wanted to avoid doing a union.

Answer (score -1):

Ive come up with a sql using Union to add Total to the end of your results. You can see the [query here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12ad9/44)

```
SELECT country, province, SUM(population) as population, 0 as OrderBy
FROM census
GROUP BY country, province
UNION
SELECT country, province, population, 1 as OrderBy FROM (
  SELECT 'Total' as country, '' as province, SUM(population) as population
  FROM census
)
ORDER BY OrderBy;
```