# Data rows plus totals row in a single scan

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, grouping-sets

Imagine we have following data in a table:

```
groupName  volume  class  mark
---------- ------- ------ ----
group1     50      1      o
group1     50      1      o
group1     50      1      x
group1     25      2      o
group2     25      1      x
group2     17      3      x
group2     11      2      o
group3     11      1      o
group3     19      3      x
```

And there is the need to add totals row at the end (`SUM` for volume and `NULL` for the rest of the columns).

I know that what I need can be achieved by adding total with the `union all` as:

```
select 0 as isTotal, groupName, class, mark, volume
from dataTable
union all
select 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, sum(volume)
from dataTable
order by isTotal, groupName, class
```

but this way table is scanned twice.

To avoid scanning data twice, I tried using `group by`:

```
select grouping(groupName) as isTotal, groupName, class, mark, sum(volume) as volume
from dataTable
group by grouping sets ((), (groupName, class, mark, volume))
order by isTotal, groupName, class
```

this way there is only one table scan, and I'm getting almost what I need, except that two first rows of the sample data (which are duplicates) are merged into one, and I need duplicates be kept as separate rows.

**The question:**
Is it possible to get table data with the totals row added so that table data is scanned once and duplicates are kept as a separate rows?

The desired result is what is returned by `union all` query:

```
isTotal groupName   class  mark volume
------- ----------- ------ ---- -------
0       group 1     1      o    50
0       group 1     1      o    50
0       group 1     1      x    50
0       group 1     2      o    25
0       group 2     1      x    25
0       group 2     2      o    11
0       group 2     3      x    17
0       group 3     1      o    11
0       group 3     3      x    19
1       NULL        NULL   NULL 258
```

The result returned by `group by grouping sets` query:

```
isTotal groupName  class  mark volume
------- ---------- ------ ---- -------
0       group 1    1      o    100
0       group 1    1      x    50
0       group 1    2      o    25
0       group 2    1      x    25
0       group 2    2      o    11
0       group 2    3      x    17
0       group 3    1      o    11
0       group 3    3      x    19
1       NULL       NULL   NULL 258
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934318/add-a-summary-row-with-totals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even thought you have duplicated rows, you can make them unique and fix your issue. One way to do this is using `ROW_NUMBER` function.

For example:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [groupName] VARCHAR(6)
   ,[volume] TINYINT
   ,[class] TINYINT
   ,[mark] CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([groupName], [volume], [class], [mark])
VALUES ('group1', '50', '1', 'x')
      ,('group1', '50', '1', 'x')
      ,('group1', '50', '1', 'o')
      ,('group1', '25', '2', 'o')
      ,('group2', '25', '1', 'x')
      ,('group2', '17', '3', 'x')
      ,('group2', '11', '2', 'o')
      ,('group3', '11', '1', 'o')
      ,('group3', '19', '3', 'x');

WITH DataSource ([rowID], [groupName], [volume], [class], [mark]) AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
          ,[groupName]
          ,[volume]
          ,[class]
          ,[mark]
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT GROUPING([groupName]) as [isTotal]
      ,[groupName]
      ,[class]
      ,[mark]
      ,SUM([volume]) AS [volume]
FROM DataSource
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((), ([rowID], [groupName], [volume], [class], [mark]))
ORDER BY [isTotal]
        ,[groupName]
        ,[class];
```

will give you:

[image]

exactly the same as your initial query:

```
select 0 as isTotal, groupName, class, mark, volume
from @DataSource
union all
select 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, sum(volume)
from @DataSource
order by isTotal, groupName, class
```

If you compare the execution plans you can see only one table scan is performed:

[image]