# SQL - Combine another SELECT query with a JOIN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, where-clause, with-statement

I found this post on stackoverflow, [Add a summary row with totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934318/add-a-summary-row-with-totals)

What I'm trying to accomplish is just that, but with the converted DURATION field I have listed in this WITH statement below. I'm trying to TOTAL up the Durations column for that day(24 hr period). I don't know if it's possible. Let me know. Thank you!

```
;WITH dupes AS
(
    SELECT 
        CALLER_PHONE, DIALED_PHONE
    FROM 
        dbo.PBXDATA
    GROUP BY 
        CALLER_PHONE, DIALED_PHONE
)
SELECT 
    c.CALL_TIME, c.SALES_REP, c.CALL_TYPE, c.FLAG1, 
    COALESCE(NULLIF(c.FLAG3, 'NULL'),'') AS FLAG3, 
    ISNULL(dupes.CALLER_PHONE, '') + ISNULL(dupes.DIALED_PHONE,'') AS PHONE, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), c.DURATION, 108) AS DURATION
FROM 
    dupes
JOIN 
    dbo.PBXDATA c ON dupes.CALLER_PHONE = c.CALLER_PHONE 
                  OR dupes.DIALED_PHONE = c.DIALED_PHONE
WHERE 
    (c.SALES_REP LIKE 'Doug%' OR 
     c.SALES_REP LIKE 'Nick%' OR 
     c.SALES_REP LIKE 'Bob%' OR 
     c.SALES_REP LIKE 'Joe%' OR 
     c.SALES_REP LIKE 'John%')
    AND (c.CALL_TIME >= DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0,   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)))
    AND (c.CALL_TIME <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)))
    AND DURATION = (SELECT CAST(DATEADD(S, SUM(DATEDIFF(S, '00:00:00', DURATION)), '00:00:00') AS TIME) 
                    FROM dbo.PBXDATA) 
ORDER BY 
    c.CALL_TIME;
```

Comment: Can you give us tables structure ,input and desired out put ? It's hard to understand what you want.

Comment: I apologize for that. Thank you for reminding me. Below is the link. http://www.tvlift.com/beta-test/table.png

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an overall total for the **Duration** in your **dupes** table, you can just sum your Duration there.

```
;WITH dupes AS
(
SELECT CALLER_PHONE, DIALED_PHONE, convert(varchar(8), SUM(c.DURATION), 108) AS Total_Time 
FROM dbo.PBXDATA
GROUP BY CALLER_PHONE, DIALED_PHONE
)
```

And add **, Total_Time** to your SELECT statement.

If you have multiple days in your query, you would need to add the date field in the **dupes** and add it as part of the JOIN's **ON** clause.