# Can you add another row to a CASE statement that provides a TOTAL?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I want to know if I can add a TOTAL count to the last row of my case statement:

```sql
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN weight <= 10 THEN "very small"
        WHEN weight > 10 AND weight <= 30 THEN "small"
        WHEN weight > 30 AND weight <= 50 THEN "medium"
        WHEN weight > 50 AND weight <= 85 THEN "large"
        WHEN weight > 85 THEN "very large"
        END AS dog_weights, count(weight) as count
FROM dogs
GROUP BY dog_weights;
```

**Table from Output**

```
| Dog_Weights | Count |
|-------------|-------|
| Very Small  | 20    |
| Small       | 20    |
| Medium      | 40    |
| Large       | 20    |
```

**Desired Table**

```
| Dog_Weights | Count |
|-------------|-------|
| Very Small  | 20    |
| Small       | 20    |
| Medium      | 40    |
| Large       | 20    |
| Total       | 100   |
```

Would I use a sub-query for this? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934318/add-a-summary-row-with-totals ?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method in MySQL is to use `rollup`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN weight <= 10 THEN 'very small'
             WHEN weight > 10 AND weight <= 30 THEN 'small'
             WHEN weight > 30 AND weight <= 50 THEN 'medium'
             WHEN weight > 50 AND weight <= 85 THEN 'large'
             WHEN weight > 85 THEN 'very large'
         END) AS dog_weights,
        count(*) as count
FROM dogs
GROUP BY dog_weights WITH rollup;
```

To get `TOTAL`, I think you need a subquery:

Assuming that `weight` is never `NULL`, you can do:

```
SELECT COALESCE(dog_weights, 'total') as dog_weights, count
FROM (SELECT (CASE WHEN weight <= 10 THEN 'very small'
                   WHEN weight > 10 AND weight <= 30 THEN 'small'
                   WHEN weight > 30 AND weight <= 50 THEN 'medium'
                   WHEN weight > 50 AND weight <= 85 THEN 'large'
                   WHEN weight > 85 THEN 'very large'
               END) AS dog_weights,
              count(*) as count
      FROM dogs
      GROUP BY dog_weights WITH rollup
     ) d
```