# MySQL UNION ALL SELECT Issue on getting all the SUM per column

Tags: mysql, sql

I wish to get the SUM of the product per column, not sure if the **UNION ALL SELECT** can handle the desired result considering that the first column is concatenated.

**Here is the code:**

```
                 SUM(product.product_id = 1) AS Soda,
                 SUM(product.product_id = 2) AS Liquor,
                 SUM(product.product_id = 3) AS Lemon,
                 SUM(product.product_id = 4) AS Mango,
                 SUM(product.product_id = 5) AS Inhaler,
                 SUM(1) AS Count

FROM line_item
JOIN product USING (product_id)
JOIN ( SELECT    0 lowest,  500 highest UNION
       SELECT  501   , 1000             UNION
       SELECT 1001   , 1500             UNION
       SELECT 1501   , 2000             UNION
       SELECT 2001   , 2500 ) ranges ON product.price * line_item.quantity BETWEEN ranges.lowest AND ranges.highest
GROUP BY ranges.lowest, ranges.highest

UNION ALL SELECT '','','','','','',
(
    SELECT 
    COUNT(product.price * line_item.quantity)
    FROM (line_item
    INNER JOIN product ON line_item.product_id = product.product_id)
);

**The output:**
+-------------+------+--------+-------+-------+---------+-------+
| Revenue     | Soda | Liquor | Lemon | Mango | Inhaler | Count |
+-------------+------+--------+-------+-------+---------+-------+
| 0 - 500     | 4    | 0      | 4     | 0     | 1       |     9 |
| 501 - 1000  | 0    | 0      | 0     | 2     | 0       |     2 |
| 1001 - 1500 | 0    | 1      | 0     | 2     | 2       |     5 |
| 1501 - 2000 | 0    | 2      | 0     | 0     | 1       |     3 |
| 2001 - 2500 | 0    | 1      | 0     | 0     | 0       |     1 |
|             |      |        |       |       |         |    20 |
+-------------+------+--------+-------+-------+---------+-------+

Thank for your help.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ROLL UP operator? Seems like there's a similar problem to yours: [Add a summary row with totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934318/add-a-summary-row-with-totals)

Comment: I tried. It actually works but it gives me a NULL value and reorders the revenue.

Comment: Instead of posting an answer which merely links to another answer, please instead [flag the question](/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused.  You are defining the ranges already.  If you want a range that encompasses all the values, just add it in:

```
FROM line_item JOIn
     product
     USING (product_id) JOIN
     ( SELECT    0 lowest,  500 highest UNION ALL
       SELECT  501   , 1000             UNION ALL
       SELECT 1001   , 1500             UNION ALL
       SELECT 1501   , 2000             UNION ALL
       SELECT 2001   , 2500             UNION ALL
       SELECT    0   , 2500             
-------^ all encompassing range
     ) ranges
     ON product.price * line_item.quantity BETWEEN ranges.lowest AND ranges.highest
```

Voila!  This also has the summary row.