# How can I add a SUM(nvarchar) or COUNT row at the end of a group of results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking to add the rows 6 and 13 to the results.

[image]

```
SELECT
    ARPDisplayName0

FROM
    v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE
    
WHERE
    ARPDisplayName0 = 'Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro' or 
    ARPDisplayName0 = 'Bomgar'
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Thats normally a function of the front end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a summary row with totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934318/add-a-summary-row-with-totals)

Comment: Thanks, Dale, I saw that. But will it add it after each value?

Comment: Totally lost.  Your query returns one column, but your data has two.  The `WHERE` clause would generate an error.  Please at least put working SQL in the question if it is producing a result set.

Comment: @My9to5 Check the documentation for `rollup` to see.

Comment: @Dale K Rollup definitely looks like its it! Now need to figure out how to SUM/COUNT the nvarchar

Comment: Can you add your expected result here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use `Grouping Sets` for such items

**Example**

```
Select ARPDisplayName0
      ,ComputerName = coalesce(ComputerName,concat('Total ',sum(1)))
 From  v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE
 Group By Grouping Sets ( 
                          (ARPDisplayName0,ComputerName)
                         ,(ARPDisplayName0)
                        )
```

**Results**

```
ARPDisplayName0 ComputerName
Acrobat         Comp1
Acrobat         Comp2
Acrobat         Comp3
Acrobat         Total 3
Bomgar          Comp1
Bomgar          Comp2
Bomgar          Total 2
```

Comment: Thanks! @YourTable is just a temporary table, right? INSERT INTO is something I've steered away from

Comment: @My9to5 The (at)YourTable is just a demonstrative table variable -- see updated answer

Comment: `CASE WHEN GROUPING(ComputerName) = 1...` instead of the `COALESCE` is probably better, as it returns correct results in the face of nulls. You can also add an `ORDER BY ARPDisplayName0, GROUPING(ComputerName)` to make it neat

Comment: @Charlieface Fair comment.  In this case, I suspect the ORDER BY carries a bit more weight.  I can't imagine a value of a NULL ComputerName.