# SQL How to get % of row total

Tags: sql, pivot

In SQL I am trying to do a table with percentages for each row only. I've looked everywhere but can't quite get it. `count(*)/sum(count(*)) over ()` is close but that does % of everything.

Data:
ID = ['A','B',...]
Scenario = [1,2,3,4]

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT
      ID,
      Scenario,
      count(*) as count,
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `ID`,
         `Scenario`
)
pivot(
  sum(count) as total
  for Scenario in (1,2,3,4)
)
```

Current output:

| Id / Scenario | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 4 | 1 | 3 |
| B | 2 | 7 | 5 | 6 |

This is good, but I also want to display this as % of each row so each row should add up to 100%.

Desired output:

| Id / Scenario | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20% | 40% | 10% | 30% |
| B | 10% | 45% | 25% | 30% |

How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: hi, might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934318/add-a-summary-row-with-totals

Comment: [Why should I tag-my RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you would try to do for A-1 is A-1/A? Would Scenario/Total * 100 give you the correct value? then just concat a % sign

Comment: Yes, A-1 / A, A-2 / A, etc. is what I'm looking for. But how to do that? Sorry, somewhat new to SQL..